# Need help to calculate RSI in python with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, finance

I want to calculate the rsi of the close prices of a csv table but the result is not accurate

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

    
def calcRSIfromCSV(fname): 
    data = pd.read_csv(fname)
    pos = 0
    numPos = 0
    neg = 0
    numNeg = 0
    
    for x in data.index:
        if (x != 0):
            diff = data['close'][x] - data['close'][x-1] 
        else:
            diff = 0
        print(diff)
        if (diff > 0):
            pos += diff
            numPos += 1
        elif (diff < 0):
            neg += abs(diff)
            numNeg += 1

    aG = (pos / numPos)
    aL = (neg / numNeg)
    rs = ( aG / aL)
    rsi = 100 - (100 / (1 + rs))
    print(rsi)
    
calcRSIfromCSV('Daten.csv')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIjOb.png)

The code should deliever a RSI of 58 but I get a result of 52 what am I doing wrong?